# N0.C1.D0 meaning in dimm config?

Tags: linux, memory, xeon

Could somebody explain to me what this code means in dimm config? I have E2680 server.  Below is the log:

```
 N0.C0.D0 : 16 GB (1Rx4) DDR3 - bank: 8, row: 0x20000, col: 0x800,  800 8-6-6 cwl= 5 (6622206A)
 N0.C1.D0 : 16 GB (1Rx4) DDR3 - bank: 8, row: 0x20000, col: 0x800,  800 8-6-6 cwl= 5 (6622206A)
 N0.C2.D0 : 16 GB (1Rx4) DDR3 - bank: 8, row: 0x20000, col: 0x800,  800 8-6-6 cwl= 5 (6622206A)
 N0.C3.D0 : 16 GB (1Rx4) DDR3 - bank: 8, row: 0x20000, col: 0x800,  800 8-6-6 cwl= 5 (6622206A)
```

Comment: Please provide as much information as possible. Are you seeing other error messages or warnings? What log did this information come from?

Comment: I am just asking what the codes mean to learn.  No errors. Not sure why i got -1 :)

Answer (score 1):

N=NUMA Node
C=Channel
D=DIMM Slot

Don't know what the '6622206A' means, part number perhaps?